# Binary File Reads Negative Integers After Writing

Tags: c++, fstream, binaryfiles, bit-shift

I came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516027/writing-4-bits-to-a-binary-file-with-ofstream/26516209#26516209) where I wanted to write 2 integers to a single byte that were garunteed to be between 0-16 (4 bits each).

Now if I close the file, and run a different program that reads....

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    char byteToRead;
    file.seekg(i, std::ios::beg);
    file.read(&byteToRead, sizeof(char));
    bool correct = file.bad();
    unsigned int num1 = (byteToRead >> 4);
    unsigned int num2 = (byteToRead & 0x0F);
}
```

The issue is, sometimes this works but other times I'm having the first number come out negative and the second number is something like 10 or 9 all the time and they were most certainly not the numbers I wrote!

So here, for example, the first two numbers work, but the next number does not. For examplem, the output of the read above would be:

```
At byte 0, num1 = 5 and num2 = 6
At byte 1, num1 = 4294967289 and num2 = 12
```

At byte 1, num1 should be 9. It seems the 12 writes fine but the 9 << 4 isn't working. The byteToWrite on my end is `byteToWrite -100 'œ''`

I checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230676/reading-binary-from-a-file-gives-negative-number) which has a similar problem I think but I feel like my endian is right here.

Comment: You're reading into `byteToRead` but building the numbers from `myNums`.

Comment: Typo when writing the question, thank you

Comment: You probably also want to use unsigned numbers when you do this, to avoid sign extension when you shift them.

Comment: Why are you using `seekp(i/2)`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - because Im storing 2 numbers in 1 byte. So if I'm at i = 2 or i = 3, I want to write to byte position 1. In the example I should floor on odd numbers, sorry

Comment: You need to use `unsigned` integers when using bit manipulation, especially right shifting.

Comment: You should build up a byte and write the byte.  You don't need the `seekp`.  Something like `if (i%2 == 1) { write byte to file}`.

Comment: Im double incrementing i - I increment in the for loop and at the end so I never hit an odd number. I just realized the example, yet again, didn't have myNums[i+1] when storing the right half of the byte. Apologies X.x

Comment: About to comment, but you changed the code once again. Copy the exact code and the exact output.

Comment: So if I change the ints to unsigned ints, is there anyway to make sure the character is never storing negative? If I change it to unsigned char, the fstream complains because it demands a signed char pointer.

Comment: Updated with unsigned integers and clarified output for the previous example. You can see that 5 and 6 work. But 9 does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right-shift operator preserves the value of the left-most bit. If the left-most bit is 0 before the shift, it will still be 0 after the shift; if it is 1, it will still be 1 after the shift. This allow to preserve the value's sign.

In your case, you combine 9 (0b1001) with 12 (0b1100), so you write 0b10011100 (0x9C). The bit #7 is 1.

When byteToRead is right-shifted, you get 0b11111001 (0xF9), but it is implicitly converted to an int. The convertion from char to int also preserve the value's sign, so it produce 0xFFFFFFF9. Then the implicit int is implicitly converted to a unsigned int. So num1 contains 0xFFFFFFF9 which is 4294967289.

There is 2 solutions:

- cast byteToRead into a unsigned char when doing the right-shift;
- apply a mask to the shift's result to only keep the 4 bits you want.

Comment: The conversion from char to int happens before the right-shift

Answer (score 1):

The problem originates with `byteToRead >> 4` .  In C, any arithmetic operations are performed in at least `int` precision. So the first thing that happens is that `byteToRead` is promoted to int.

These promotions are value-preserving.  Your system has plain `char` as signed, i.e. having range `-128` through to `127`. Your char might have been initially `-112` (bit pattern `10010000`), and then after promotion to int it retains its value of `-112` (bit pattern `11111...1110010000`).

The right-shift of a negative value is *implementation-defined* but a common implementation is to do an "arithmetic shift", i.e. perform division by two; so you end up with the result of `byteToRead >> 4` being `-7` (bit pattern `11111....111001`).

Converting `-7` to `unsigned int` results in `UINT_MAX - 6` which is 4295967289, because unsigned arithmetic is defined as wrapping around mod `UINT_MAX+1` .

---

To fix this you need to convert to unsigned before performing the arithmetic . You could cast (or alias) `byteToRead` to `unsigned char`, e.g.:

```
unsigned char byteToRead;
file.read( (char *)&byteToRead, 1 );
```